# click on close tab the tab can't remove array list

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a prime face application. It have menu and tab. when i click on menu item on menu-bar it insert a **value** to a array List in manage bean and open tab in xhtml page.and when i click on close tab on tab it remove the value of tab from array list and close the tab. But when i include a page in any tab and the page have inputText and the input text required=true then When i close the page and that time the text filed have no data the tab data can't remove from array List in managed bean.

**for menubar and output Tab**

```
<h:form id="menu">                
        <p:menubar autoDisplay="true">
           <p:submenu id="student" label="Student">       
                <p:menuitem id="studentAdmission" value="Student Admission" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="StudentAdmission" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem id="studentList" value="Student Profile" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="StudentProfile" />
                </p:menuitem>                        
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu id="registration" label="Registration">
                <p:menuitem id="registrationAdd" value="Subject Registration" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true"  update=":outputForm">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="SubjectRegistration"/>                                 
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem id="registrationList" value="List of Registration" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="RegistrationList" />
                </p:menuitem>                        
            </p:submenu>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>       
    <h:form id="outputForm">
        <p:tabView id="outputTab">
            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{ajaxBean.closeTab}"/>
            <c:forEach items="#{ajaxBean.chcekItem}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                <p:tab id="#{item}" title="#{item}" closable="true">                            
                    <ui:include src="#{bundle[item]}"/>   

                </p:tab>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
```

Any one here help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the question i use

```
 <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{ajaxBean.closeTab}"/>
```

for close tab

and solution that i found is

```
<p:ajax event="tabClose" immediate="true" listener="#{ajaxBean.closeTab}"/>
```

that's means if we want to close tab any way and want to send `tabClose` `action` to `managedbean` then we have to use `immediate="true"`